# 4 Way Switching Wiring Diagram Nightmare

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, multiway-switch

I am having trouble making my 4 way switch working in the home I just bought (quite an old one). As of now, I don't want to remove the light fixture as it quite big and it will be a big trouble... but using a tracer, it looks like the "red" wire emphasized in the picture goes to the light fixture. I don't understand that part: I tested and in order for the light to open, I simply have to make the Power touch the Red Wire. I have never seen that before... a Red wire that seems to go to the lamp fixture itself[image].

Can someone help me understand what is going?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in the USA?

Comment: Your diagram is not a standard wiring diagram of any kind so it's pretty hard to tell what is going on. Please try redrawing the diagram so it's easier to follow and/or including photos of each electrical box.

Comment: Can you post photos clearly showing the back of the big switch box shown in the top left of your diagram please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think someone just did the coloring nonstandard; they simply used red to the fixture for whatever reason. Also, your diagram doesn't show a red between the 4-way and 3-way switches. I'll assume that's an oversight and it's actually there, because if not, you have bigger problems...

That said, there are a couple of things possibly at play. First, the black hot in the big box could be a separate circuit, not intended for the light fixture in question. Outside lights are often on a different circuit. Second, the black line in question could indeed be the power for the fixture, and you have a three-way setup where the power and fixture are in the same box. You'll need to look at the other three-way switch to know:

Three-way switches have two brass screws and a black screw. The brass screws are the travelers and the black screw is the common. In an ideal world, one three-way box would have the power coming in, and the other would have the power out to the fixture. You'd connect the incoming power to the common on one switch, and the fixture's hot wire to the common on the other switch. You then run the red/black traveler in between, connected to the brass screws on both switches, and you're done. The neutrals and ground simply connect to each other all the way across.

In the more-complicated situation of the power and fixture hots being at the same box, the typical method is to use the white of the traveler wire to carry the switched hot:

- The incoming power goes to the common screw of the switch in that box
- The traveler red and black connect to the brass screws of that switch
- The white neutral of the incoming power line connects to the neutral of the fixture
- The white *of the traveler* connects to the hot of the fixture

At the other end:

- The red and black again attach to the brass screws
- The *white* attaches to the common (black) screw

So what you need to do is look at the other three-way switch. You should find one of two things: a) a single red-black-white-ground coming in with the white attached to the black screw, or b) two lines, one black-white-ground and the other red-black-white-ground, with the single black wire on the black screw, and the whites attached together.

In the former case, use a continuity tester to check and see if the white coming in with the travelers (the red-black-white-ground from the 4-way switch) gets connected and disconnected by operating the switches. If so, that needs to go to your fixture hot (red), and the hot black line needs to go to the black screw on the 3-way in the big box.

In the latter case, the hot you've found in the big box is unrelated; as I said, likely another circuit. The fixture hot (red) should be on the black screw of the 3-way in the big box, and everything should operate correctly.

Comment: Did the trick!!! Thanks a lot for your explanation.